# javascript how to see the razor variable? and set checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

have an edit form that has checkboxes.  if the checkbox is checked it uses script to send a yes/no value onto a hiddenfor( variable.

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PTModel1, htmlAttributes: new { @class =      "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
        @Html.CheckBox("checkbox")
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PTModel1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

script code:

```
$("#checkbox1").on("click", function () {
                var myCheckbox1 = $("#checkbox1");
                if (myCheckbox1.is(":checked")) {
                    $("#PTModel1").val("Yes");
                }
                else {
                    $("#PTModel1").val("No");
                }
            });
```

ok on the Create and Edit methods in the mvc bootstrap forms it works fine along with some script to add the yes/no;  but the problem happens when going to do an Edit, if the value IS checked and IS already set to Yes, it always defaults to no, and the checkbox is not checked.  how to make a checkbox checked if the value thats now in the form PTModel1 variable is "yes" ??

```
 <script>
   $(window).load(function () {

       switch (("#PTModel1").val) {

           case "Yes": $("#checkbox1").checked;
               alert("in switch case");
               break;
           default: alert("in switch case default" + "#PTModel1");
    }
});
</script>
```

question: how to set the checkbox, if the value of the variable is "yes" ? the syntax isnt doing what i expect.

2nd question: at one time i had this saving a tiny icon image of a checked checkbox, so in the index view it would display the icon.  whatever makes it save and display the state.  the checkbox must reflect the checkedness of the checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the mistakes highlighted in below code:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    switch ($("#PTModel1").val()) {
        //  ^                 ^^

        case "Yes":
            $("#checkbox1").prop('checked', true);
            //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            alert("in switch case");
            break;
        default:
            alert("in switch case default" + "#PTModel1");
    }
});
```

**OR**

Shorter version:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', $('#PTModel1').val() == 'Yes');
});
```

**Shorter version of Event Handler**

```
$("#checkbox1").on("click", function () {
    $('#PTModel1').val($(this).is(':checked') ? 'Yes' : 'No');
});
```

Comment: THANKS so much! i am surprised at how the js will infer an if without explicitly declaring it, is this the nature of a js statement? implied if?  it works perfectly.

Comment: @MaxPower That is `ternary Operator`. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: again thanks for that reference, very helpful.  but on the load function, there is no if and no ?  the ternary from the click function is from C type syntax; but the first one is just there, implicit 1/2 ternary?  which is:  statement, result if true;

Comment: ok, something is wrong.  Firefox does not support this code, using chrome it works most of the time, hard to pinpoint.  sometimes it will save the state right, sometimes not.  if i add an alert('checkbox was checked') it seems to work every time.  take that out and its less likely.  so that suggests some timing issue.  is there a way to make this script more deterministic? is there a lock command then read/modify/write then unlock?   is there a way to make the html/script code run more reliably?